# PHP 5.5 -> 5.6: Include not working any more (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I´m moving an application from a **PHP 5.5 server to a PHP 5.6** server. The application is based on **Codeigniter 2.2**.

On the old server I had something like this in my views to include other template parts:

```
include('header.php');
```

This simple and direct include works like a charm on the old server.

On the new server I get the exception, that the **file for inclusion could not be found**.

I found out, that the PHP preprocessor tries to grab the file from the linux include paths and also from the "system/core" directory. But not from the directory where the view itself is located.

I´ve not idea what makes the difference between these two systems... Has anybody an idea where I can search for the issue?

Comment: What is the error ?? or output

Comment: also show your  code

Comment: I haven't seen include's behavior change at all. Using `include('header.php');` will check the include path first in both 5.5 and 5.6. Then, it will check the local directory. If, instead, you use `include('./header.php');`, it will ignore the include path because you have it a path.

Comment: You can normally set your own `include_path` from within PHP, you don't need to rely on the server's system-wide default.

Comment: debugging: `var_dump(getcwd(), __DIR__, getcwd() === __DIR__);` immediately before the `include`.  It should return the two paths as equal and  `true` for it to work correctly. Assuming that `header.php` is in the same directory as the script. Also, `var_dump(file_exists(__DIR__ .'/header.php'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for all your input - I´ve already tried most of these debugging attempts.

Now I digged a little deeper and **found the reason** for my problems. The **short_open_tag directive in PHP** caused the issue. Cause this new server had some slight differences in **php.ini**.

In **core/loader.php** Codeigniter tries to **replace short open tags** with normal tags, if the .ini setting for short_open_tags is disabled. For any reason this replacement isn´t working as expected and that caused my issues.

So if anyone has the same issue after moving a Codeigniter installation from one machine to another, that might be a point where you can start.

Thanks to all of you,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

> **Check the file path. Whether its inside some other folder or not.**

Also can try with

```
$this->load->view('header.php');
```

or can load header in Controller as well

---

As well there are some useful keyword.

1. **APPPATH** - Outputs application path. Ex `application/`